# How do I dismantle a Saniflo Compact to clean it?

Tags: toilet

I have a Saniflo Compact that has stopped flushing. The motor runs but no flush. I used Zep descaling solution first, and a whole bunch a junk came loose. Took the back of the inflow and outtake hoses off and cleaned out as much as I could. But I can't see or get to the macerator section? Do I have to take the whole toilet apart? and how do I do that? I am not a plumber, but a good handygirl, don't wanna break anything. Thanks for any help. And I did go buy the expensive Saniflo descaler,, let it sit all night,, and nothing, Motor still running, no flush. I believe it needs a good cleaning, since it's over 5 years now, and i've just discovered this issue!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [good Utube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ1rBxESEhU) that explains how to clean the macerator and explains how they get plugged with things like expensive toilet paper and dental floss on occasion moving the pump impeller with a screw driver can break things loose. There were several videos to watch.